# How to use Git-Media in C#

Tags: c#, git

I am using git (Git Sharp) in a C# application. Now I want to use Git-Media in C#. Are there any tools available which will allow me to use Git-Media in C# applications?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are NO tools available to use Git-media from C#.

You just need to see if you can interface with the Ruby code from your C# application. Maybe you should rephrase your question to reflect this?